# Oracle APEX 5.0: add items values to dynamic URL

Tags: oracle-apex

I have table containing data in columns `apex_page, apex_to_item, apex_with_values` like this:

```
apex_to_page: 6010
apex_to_item: P6010_XSRCS_ID,P6010_XSVER_ID
apex_with_values: XSRCS_ID,ID
```

During rendering of the page I want to parse this values (URL destination, list of items to set, list of values from current page) and create URLs based on it. For example: `f?p=112:6010:4314006485638::NO::P6010_XSRCS_ID,P6010_XSVER_ID:100,200&cs=3LNhUQHJiAOOaiw3C_z3bHGtc4Us0LZV-D7ZMQhG0Z3EzCLeJpT8f--YA7SFOoD4xQD2C45qrv2PVxvwBY39qBA`

I.e. I want to take current values of XSRCS_ID,ID items of current page (100,200) and insert it into URL. When there is only one value to pass I have solution:

```
SELECT name label,
       APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(p_url => 'f?p=' || NV('APP_ID') || ':' || apex_page || ':' || NV('APP_SESSION') || '::NO::' || apex_to_items || ':' || NV('P' || :APP_PAGE_ID || '_' || apex_with_values), p_checksum_type => 'SESSION') apex_url
   FROM ...
```

When there are more that one item to pass I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT name label,
       APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(p_url => 'f?p=' || NV('APP_ID') || ':' || apex_page || ':' || NV('APP_SESSION') || '::NO::' || apex_to_items || ':' || regexp_replace(apex_with_values, '([^,]+)', NV('P' || :APP_PAGE_ID || '_\1')), p_checksum_type => 'SESSION') apex_url
       ...
  FROM ...
```

and it isn't worked.

Is there a way to extract values from page and insert it into URL?

Comment: try with &YOUR_ITEM_NAME. (& before name and . (dot) after)

Comment: You said, "I want to form URL dynamically, extract current values of items on page and replace item names with it in my URL." I'm not sure what you mean. If you're creating the URL with APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL when the page is rendering, how is it going to include the "current values of items on the page"? Please explain what you're trying to do in more deail.

Comment: @DanMcGhan I've changed question text

Comment: I have a feeling that you're moving in the wrong direction. I've never seen anyone store APEX item names and try to map them as you're doing. The goal seems to be to do something generic but I wonder if there's a better approach. I can't offer a better solution since I don't know what you're trying to do functionally, only technically. At any rate, to generate the correct URL, you'll need to create a stored function that takes in the relevant parameters and returns the URL. When you have multiple items, you'll need to loop over them to build the URL correctly.

Comment: @hinotf Did you still need help with this? Maybe an example?

Comment: @DanMcGhan no, thank you. I've changed logic design

Comment: @DanMcGhan can you please share an example? I am facing the same issue. I want to pass multiple values but I cannot get the syntax right

Answer (score 0):

You need to add coma separated values. First you need to combine all the **Keys**   together (coma separated) and then the  **values** also coma separated.

Here is an example

```
l_url := APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(
    p_url => 'f?p=' || l_app || ':'||apex_application.g_x01||':'||l_session||'::NO::'
    ||l_item_item1|| ','||l_item_item2|| 
    ','||l_item_item3||','||l_item_item4||':'
    ||apex_application.g_x02|| ','||apex_application.g_x03||','|| 
    apex_application.g_x04||','|| apex_application.g_x05,
    p_checksum_type => 'SESSION');
htp.p(l_url);
```